# Update email address in Mailchimp using Mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to sync a person record from my DB to mailchimp. I can update all fields except email. Email i can update only once. On updating again it throws an error. I am using their java API. This is what i am doing -

```
emailType = "";
replaceInterests = false; 

mergeVars.put("EMAIL", rs.getString("email"));

Boolean rc = mcServices.listUpdateMember(apiKey, listId, mailChimpId, mergeVars, emailType, replaceInterests);
```

The error message on reupdating is -

com.nwire.mailchimp.MailChimpServiceException: oldEmail@email.com is not a member of listName
 at com.nwire.mailchimp.MailChimpServiceFactory$ClientFactory$1.invoke(MailChimpServiceFactory.java:190)
 at $Proxy0.listUpdateMember(Unknown Source)
 at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.TestMCList1.updateDetails(TestMCList1.java:121)
 at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.TestMCList1.sync(TestMCList1.java:92)
 at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.TestMCList1.run(TestMCList1.java:52)
 at com.nwire.mailchimp.test.TestMCList1.main(TestMCList1.java:35)

Please note, oldEmail@email.com in the error message is the original email address in Mailchimp shich i have successfully updated once, but still shows up on reupdations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are using as `mailChimpId`, but this is the email as well. So, if the email changes, this variable should change as well. In your case it will look like this:

```
String email = rs.getString("email");
mergeVars.put("EMAIL", email);
Boolean rc = mcServices.listUpdateMember(apiKey, listId, email, mergeVars, emailType, replaceInterests);
```

I hope this helps (I wrote this Java wrapper and this works just fine on my server).

Comment: Thanks .. But i don't think this works. Because how will Mailchimp know which contact's email has to be changed (we are just passing the updated email, not the email stored with mailchimp). I am using mailchimpId - unique id assigned by mailchimp to each contact.

Comment: I would suggest using the MailChimp API support group. http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss. You can also email their support.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the old email address ie

**mergeVars.put("EMAIL", email);**

you define the new one in the following way:

**mergeVars.put("NEW-EMAIL", new-email);**

So you need both the old and the new addresses in orer to update it

Comment: Although in my case I'm using PHP you should not use both EMAIL and NEW-EMAIL at the same time. The "old email" is by the "email_address" key, and then you can either use merge_vars['EMAIL'] or merge_vars['NEW-EMAIL'] to update the subscriber address. My understanding of your answer is that you have to have both, [which is incorrect](https://twitter.com/MailChimp_API/status/351674145609748480).