# Can't get MailChimp API listUpdateMember to change a user's email address

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use the MailChimp API to update an email address of a member when they change their email in our web app.

I'm using the [Laravel MailChimp bundle](https://github.com/swt83/laravel-mailchimp) and it's been working great (I can subscribe users, update groupings, update name etc), but I must have the merge_vars or something incorrect.

I use this:

```
$member_details = array(
    // grabbed from config and working (also API key handled by bundle)
    'id' => $id,
    // passed from function - corresponds to the old email address
    'email_address' => $mailchimp_old_email,
    'merge_vars' => array(
        // Old email again?
        'EMAIL' => $mailchimp_old_email,     
        // new email address        
        'NEW-EMAIL' => $mailchimp_new_email, 
    ),
    'replace_interests' => FALSE,
);

$response = Mailchimp::listUpdateMember($member_details);
```

So "$response = 1", which made me think it had worked, but the user email has not changed when I view the subscriber list on MailChimp.

The 1.3 API docs have listSubscribe detailing the merge_vars "EMAIL" and "NEW-EMAIL" and I read about it on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140843/update-email-address-in-mailchimp-using-mailchimp-api). I did try using listSubscribe again even though it was an existing member, but this failed with a $response saying the member is already subscribed.

Any recommendations on where I might be going wrong? I haven't found a clear example of this sort of listUpdateMember api usage.

Comment: Awesome, this question just earned me the 'tumbleweed' badge...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the answer is very simple.

https://twitter.com/MailChimp_API/status/351674145609748480

Apparently NEW-EMAIL isn't needed at all in the merge_vars - just EMAIL.

So the working code in my case is:

```
$member_details = array(
    // grabbed from config and working (also API key handled by bundle)
    'id' => $id,
    // passed from function - corresponds to the old email address
    'email_address' => $mailchimp_old_email,
    'merge_vars' => array(
        // new email address        
        'EMAIL' => $mailchimp_new_email,     
    ),
    'replace_interests' => FALSE,
);

$response = Mailchimp::listUpdateMember($member_details);
```

This works straight out. Feels like "NEW-EMAIL" really isn't necessary (or EMAIL should be removed and just use "NEW-EMAIL" as it's somewhat more descriptive of what's happening).

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated to use MailChimp API v3, there's a new way to do it.

Use `patch` or `put` method on `/lists/members` endpoint.

`email_address` is a "top-level" property on the object you push (on the same level as `merge_fields`, which is called `merge_vars` in API 2) and represents the new email address.

[MailChimp Documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/)